# How to dispay and hide div in angularjs

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am having a loader in my screen which will be displayed on the screen until page gets loaded or page gives any error.

I am having a `div` where I have the loader...

```
<div id:loader class="loading">
```

...and I am trying to show and hide based on the page load status.

How can I hide and show the loader? Here in my js code:

```
oninit() { 
    $scope.loader.showDiv = true;
    function(success) { 
        $scope.loader.showDiv= false;
    } 
}
```

But it is not working. Now it is running continuously on the page. Any helping hand on achieving the same.

Comment: You seem to have missed something in your question.

Comment: on init()
{

function(success)
{
$scope.loader.show = false
}

}

Comment: Use the [ng-show directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and the [ng-hide directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show Try this

```
<div id:loader class="loading" ng-show="showDiv">
```

Still use your init function to set showDiv = true or false

Or set a scope for loading in your init

```
$scope.isLoading = true;
```

Put this in your div

```
ng-show="!isLoading"
```

Set it to false when page is loaded

```
$scope.isLoading = false;
```